# Generating distinct random numbers using import random python

Tags: python, random

I am wondering how the following code works:

```
def gen_game():
    rst = set()
    while len(rst) < 4:
        rst.add(random.randint(0, 9))
    print(rst)
    return "".join(str(i) for i in rst)
```

I understand that the above function will generate random numbers and add that together beside each other. What I am concern is that how do I know if the number do not generate distinct numbers?

For example, using random.randint(0,9). How come I do not get double 9s? or triple 9s? or quadruple 9s?

Comment: this basically implements [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=choice#random.sample). why not use that directly then?

Comment: This is because `rst` is a `set`. A set will only contain distinct objects (even when you try to add another 9)

Comment: You're using a set?

Comment: Thank you it answered my question. one more question. why do we use set instead or list? is there a particular reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rst = set()`

Sets cannot contain duplicates. If you attempt to add a duplicate, it will reject it.

Comment: out of curiousity why do we use 'set' instead of 'list'? Is there a particular reason?

Comment: In case you want a data structure that doesn't contain duplicates. It can be used as more of a contract. You're saying "if you use this, you know there won't be duplicates". For example, if you're passing a list of US States, there shouldn't be any duplicates, so you use a Set.